# How do I increase the maximum number of lines listed in the Visual Studio Output Window?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ide

I am debugging a program which generates a lot of output in the Visual Studio Output window. When I try to copy and paste the output to a file I find that not all the output is retained. A lot of output from the beginning of the debugging session is lost.

I looked under options/settings but could not find any option to set the size of the output buffer.

How can I increase the maximum number of lines that the Output Window will retain in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm just curious... why the downvotes and the vote to close?

I've been using Visual Studio since the late 90s and I really don't know if there is an option to change the maximum number of lines in the output window. I've only had the need for this recently.